# R How to call a function on its own output

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, data.table

Here is the situation.  I have a `data.table` and I want to collapse rows of this table based on some criteria.  I have written a function, but it only operates 2 rows at a time.  So the most rows I could collapse with one round of the function is 50% (i.e. start with 1000 rows, round 1 of function leaves us with 500).  At this point, it seems that the logical thing to do is to run the function again, on the output produced, so that I can collapse the rows further, and then do this again, and again until I have collapsed all possible rows.

my function

```
fun = function(x) {
<stuff the function does>
return(output) }
```

I would like to call the function on its own output, and repeat this until the output is no longer changed with further function calls.

I have tried this:

```
fun = function(x) {
<stuff>
output = resulting_dt
while (!identical(x,output)) {fun(output)}
return(output)
}
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '__' not found
```

I am sure there is a way to make this work, but I am fairly new to R programming, this being the first real program I have had to write, so any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

## **EDIT: I went with the a combination of the solutions provided by @gregor and @42- **

```
fun = function(x) {
<stuff>
output = resulting_dt
if (!identical(x,output)) {return(Recall(output))}
else {return(output)}
}
```

And for those of you who were interested in a reproducible function, I was having trouble coming up with one (it was taking forever), so here is the big ugly function I was actually working with:

```
fun <- function (object)
{
  num = 1
  n = 1
  temp = list()
  while (n <= object[, length(chr)]) 
    { 
    if ( (n == (object[, length(chr)])) &&
         !( (object[n,chr] == object[n-1,chr]) && 
            (abs(object[n,end] - object[n-1,start]) < 500) &&
            (((object[n,meth.diff] >= 0) == (object[n-1,meth.diff] >= 0)) || 
             ((object[n,meth.diff] < 0) == (object[n-1,meth.diff] < 0)))))
         {
         x = data.table(
           chr=object[n,chr], start=object[n,start], end=object[n,end], 
           meth.diff=object[n,meth.diff], mean_KO=object[n,mean_KO], 
           mean_WT=object[n,mean_WT], coverage_KO=object[n,coverage_KO], 
           coverage_WT=object[n,coverage_WT]
         )
         temp[[num]] = x
         n = n + 1 
         num = num + 1
         }
    else if ( (object[n,chr] == object[n+1,chr]) && 
          (abs(object[n,end] - object[n+1,start]) < 500) &&
          (((object[n,meth.diff] >= 0) == (object[n+1,meth.diff] >= 0)) || 
             ((object[n,meth.diff] < 0) == (object[n+1,meth.diff] < 0)))) 
      {
      x = data.table(
        chr=object[n,chr], start=object[n,start], end=object[n+1, end], meth.diff= mean(c(object[n,meth.diff], object[n+1,meth.diff])), 
        mean_KO=(((object[n,mean_KO] * object[n,coverage_KO])/(object[n,coverage_KO] + object[n+1,coverage_KO])) +
                   ((object[n+1,mean_KO] * object[n+1,coverage_KO])/(object[n,coverage_KO] + object[n+1,coverage_KO]))),
        mean_WT=(((object[n,mean_WT] * object[n,coverage_WT])/(object[n,coverage_WT] + object[n+1,coverage_WT])) +
                   ((object[n+1,mean_WT] * object[n+1,coverage_WT])/(object[n,coverage_WT] + object[n+1,coverage_WT]))),
        coverage_KO=(object[n,coverage_KO] + object[n+1,coverage_KO]),
        coverage_WT=(object[n,coverage_WT] + object[n+1,coverage_WT])
        )
      x[, meth.diff := (mean_KO - mean_WT) ]
      temp[[num]] = x
      n = n + 2
      num = num + 1
      }
    else 
      {
        x = data.table(
          chr=object[n,chr], start=object[n,start], end=object[n,end], 
          meth.diff=object[n,meth.diff], mean_KO=object[n,mean_KO], 
          mean_WT=object[n,mean_WT], coverage_KO=object[n,coverage_KO], 
          coverage_WT=object[n,coverage_WT]
          )
        temp[[num]] = x
        n = n + 1 
        num = num + 1
      }
  }
  result = rbindlist(temp)
  #print(result)
  while (!identical(object,result)){fun(result)}
  else {return(result)}
}
```

AND an example input data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt = structure(list(chr = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1"), start = c(842326, 855423, 
855426, 855739, 855771, 880164, 880182, 880262, 1005284, 1005315
), end = c(842327L, 855424L, 855427L, 855740L, 855772L, 880165L, 
880183L, 880263L, 1005285L, 1005316L), meth.diff = c(9.35200555410902, 
19.1839617944039, 29.6734426495636, -12.3375577709254, 4.21809779410175, 
50.539925536006, 28.0168014922334, 35.1349192165154, 16.8742940741475, 
62.6063420676512), mean_KO = c(9.35200555410902, 19.1839617944039, 
32.962962583692, 1.8512250859083, 4.44417336983763, 67.0864799025607, 
31.1083297690512, 49.5746020684321, 25.1985773481452, 78.6766354515961
), mean_WT = c(0, 0, 3.28951993412841, 14.1887828568337, 0.226075575735883, 
16.5465543665547, 3.09152827681786, 14.4396828519167, 8.32428327399768, 
16.0702933839448), coverage_KO = c(139L, 55L, 55L, 270L, 270L, 
55L, 55L, 238L, 526L, 499L), coverage_WT = c(120L, 86L, 87L, 
444L, 442L, 116L, 115L, 362L, 649L, 647L)), .Names = c("chr", 
"start", "end", "meth.diff", "mean_KO", "mean_WT", "coverage_KO", 
"coverage_WT"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

ANd an example of the output I wanted (for posterity, since its not totally relevant to this question)

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = structure(list(chr = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1"), start = c(842326, 855423, 855739, 855771, 880164, 1005284
), end = c(842327L, 855427L, 855740L, 855772L, 880263L, 1005316L
), meth.diff = c(9.35200555410902, 24.4191949389371, -12.3375577709254, 
4.21809779410175, 36.7726824955192, 39.0419497750433), mean_KO = c(9.35200555410902, 
26.073462189048, 1.8512250859083, 4.44417336983763, 49.4237638627169, 
51.2332612443618), mean_WT = c(0, 1.65426725011082, 14.1887828568337, 
0.226075575735883, 12.6510813671977, 12.1913114693185), coverage_KO = c(139L, 
110L, 270L, 270L, 348L, 1025L), coverage_WT = c(120L, 173L, 444L, 
442L, 593L, 1296L)), .Names = c("chr", "start", "end", "meth.diff", 
"mean_KO", "mean_WT", "coverage_KO", "coverage_WT"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please include a real function instead of pseudo code.

Comment: The `while` will be taken care of automatically by the recursion. Replace the while line with `if (!identical(x, output)) return(fun(output))`. For debugging purposes, you may want to put in a print statement or something to check on how deep it's going.

Comment: The function is pretty long, is that okay?  I can also provide example input/output data, I just thought it might be possible to answer this question without that stuff. what do you think?

Comment: I think my answer-in-comment will work, but it assumes everything else works as expected. The ideal way to ask the question would be to create a minimal working example - something that illustrates the problem and is runnable but omits complexity that is orthogonal to this particular part of the problem.

Comment: @Gregor I tried your solution, and including a print statement helped A LOT.  The function was in fact looping over, but it turns out it was leaving off the last line of the data.table each time, so each loop made the table shorter until in the last loop there were no more rows to work with.  - It looks like I need to change the function for it to work.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the example in `?Recall`

```
fib <- function(n)
   if(n<=2) { if(n>=0) 1 else 0 } else Recall(n-1) + Recall(n-2)

> fib(10)
[1] 55
```

Comment: Thanks, this is neat. I'm using Recall to "recall" my function now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a task for `returnValue` and `on.exit` functions. You did not provide reproducible example so I will not imagine one for you.
Working example of `returnValue` can be found in my [dtq](https://github.com/jangorecki/dtq/) package. It is used there to log number of rows of object returned by arbitrary function.
`returnValue` has to be used inside `on.exit`, see [dtq/R/zzz.R#L23](https://github.com/jangorecki/dtq/blob/e589a3af00e5982ceceaaea22e1dabca570bce60/R/zzz.R#L23):

```
on.exit(
    dtq.local.log(
        timestamp = Sys.time(),
        end = if(isTRUE(getOption("dtq.log.nano")) && requireNamespace("microbenchmark", quietly=TRUE)) microbenchmark::get_nanotime()*1e-9 else proc.time()[[3L]],
        out_rows = as.integer(nrow(returnValue()))[1L]
    )
)
# hint on: as.integer(.)[1L]
# is used to return NA for object for which `nrow` will not make sense
# so to ensure length 1 integer type object is returned
```

Be aware this function was recently introduced in base R, so you may not find it if you have an old version of R.

Comment: Thanks!  The returnValue function looks like it could be really useful.  I will look into this.